# AWS Data Pipeline Escaping Comma in emr activity step section

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, escaping, amazon-data-pipeline

I am creating an aws datapipline using the architect provided in the aws web console.

Everything is setup ok, my emrcluster is configured and successfully started.

But when I am trying to submit a emr activity I come across following problem:

In the step section of the emr activity my requirement is to provide `--packages` argument with 3 packages

But as far as I understand steps in emractivity is a comma separated value and `commas (,)` are replaced with spaces in the resultant step argument.

On the other hand `--packages` argument is also a comma separated value in case of multiple packages.

Now when I am trying to pass this as argument commas get replaced with spaces that make the step invalid.

This is the statement I required as it is in the resultant emr step:

```
--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.228,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4
```

Any solution to escape the comma?

So far i try the `\\\\` way as mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html

Not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u will be using `\\\\,` it will escape the slashes and comma will get replaced.
You can try using Three slashes, same has worked for me . Like  `\\\,` .
I hope that works

Comment: Saved a lot of time Harpaul. Thanks a lot !

Comment: How can one escape comma?